# Google Authentication works on localhost, but not on domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-authenticator

Google Authentication works on localhost, but not on domain (see attached gifs).

Why does authentication work for localhost but not on domain cpspmo.com? I have added https://www.cpspmo to as an Authorized JavaScript origins URI.

Also added the following Authorized redirect URIs: https://www.cpspmo.com/signin-google https://www.cpspmo.com/Account/GoogleResponse

Here is my Startup.cs:

using CPSPMOWEB.Data;
using CPSPMOWEB.Models.EF;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace CPSPMOWEB
{
public class Startup
{
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
Configuration = configuration;
}

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var connStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("PMOUpdatesClouodConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<PMOUpdatesCloudContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connStr));

        services.AddRazorPages().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddAuthentication()
         .AddGoogle(options =>
         {
             IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
                 Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

             options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
             options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
         })

        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/account/google-login";
        })
        ;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        //app.UseCors(x => x
        //   .AllowAnyMethod()
        //   .AllowAnyHeader()
        //   .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
        //   .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

}

[localhost authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88CpW.gif)

[Domain authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvIp1.gif)

Comment: Per this [ASP.NET document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0#create-a-google-api-console-project-and-client-id)  "Create a new Google API registration in the Google Console for the production app with its production redirect URI."  Have you tried that ? If that does not work, maybe posting on stackoverflow to debug the code would be the next step as at serverfault it is more about server administration.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Than you for your response.  I did create the Google API registration with its production redirect URI.  I am still not able to login via Google on the domain.  I also posted on stackoverflow with no responses.